# Moq .NET 4.5 Missing from Nuget

Tags: .net, moq, nuget

I'm writing a windows store app and am unable to include the Moq Nuget package because it doesn't target .NET 4.5.  I can't seem to find the updated source to build the Moq package myself and target .NET 4.5  Has anyone else had success including Moq in a "Unit Test Library (Windows Store Apps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`System.Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace used for dynamic generating assemblies is missing from .NET for Windows Store apps, which means Castle DynamicProxy the base of Moq doesn't work in these apps.

However, Castle DynamicProxy allows you to save generated dynamic assemblies, so you should be able to pre-generate them and then use them, there is an [experimental fork](https://github.com/mbrit/moqrt) of Moq that has this functionality which might be useful.